# How to get the plural of a noun in GF

Tags: gf

In some situations when a user wants only the plural of a noun such as:

```hs
mkN("apple");
```

What is the best practice to get the machine to print out the result `apples` instead of printing the whole set `apple apple's apples apples'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relevant flags to `cc` in GF shell

To get `cc` (short for `compute_concrete`) in the GF shell to print only one result, you can use the flag `-one`. Like this:

```
$ gf
> i -retain alltenses/ParadigmsEng.gfo
> cc mkN "apple"
{s = table
       ParamX.Number
       [table ResEng.Case ["apple"; "apple's"];
        table ResEng.Case ["apples"; "apples'"]];
 g = ResEng.Neutr; lock_N = <>}

> cc -one mkN "apple"
apple
```

If you apply the flag for the `N`, then the first thing it prints out is the singular form. So how to fix the number to get plural instead?

### Fixed number

`N` is a category of nouns, and nouns have inflection tables. `N` can be used to create many different things: the nominative forms *apple* and *apples* can become heads of noun phrases, singular or plural. The genitive forms can become determiners ("the *apple's* sweet taste" or "all my *apples'* cores are rotten"). So `N` is open for number and case. When you print out the forms of a `N` without any extra flags, it makes sense to show them all.

If you want to go a step further, and only restrict *apples* to be plural, you need to make it into a plural `NP`:

```hs
apples_NP = mkNP aPl_Det (mkN "apple") ;
```

### Open for case

Note that a `NP` is still open for case. In fact, the inflection table of `NP` is as big as `N`'s, even though we know the number. That's because `NP`s can be made out of pronouns, and pronouns can inflect more than nouns. This is the worst case for a `NP`:

```
> cc -table i_NP
s . ResEng.NCase ResEng.Nom => I
s . ResEng.NCase ResEng.Gen => my
s . ResEng.NPAcc => me
s . ResEng.NPNomPoss => mine
```

Of course, for a NP made out of a noun, most of those fields are identical.

```
> cc -table apples_NP
s . ResEng.NCase ResEng.Nom => apples
s . ResEng.NCase ResEng.Gen => apples'
s . ResEng.NPAcc => apples
s . ResEng.NPNomPoss => apples
```

But because *some* `NP`s are different in all 4 fields, that's why the GF lincat for `NP` needs to have them.

### Display *apples* in the GF shell

To get GF shell only display *apples*, you need to create a NP out of the noun, and then call `cc -one` on the plural NP. Here's a GF file you can paste into a file called Apples.gf.

```hs
resource Apples = open ParadigmsEng, SyntaxEng in {

  oper

    apple_N : N = mkN "apple" ;

    apples_NP : NP = mkNP aPl_Det apple_N ;
}
```

Go to GF shell:

```
> i -retain Apples.gf
> cc -one apples_NP
apples
```

### Output *apples* in any other situation

If you use `apples_NP` as a subject or object in any sentence, you will get the string *apples*. If you give it as an argument to Extend.GenNP, you get a quantifier with the string *apples'*.